# WiX MSI and EXE as one EXE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix

I have a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.0 [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file that runs at the end of the install the application it installs, as this application is running as a custom action (and uses the session passed by the installer for some stuff, like writing logs..).

I need to make this install run with elevated permissions, and so I have created a "bootsrap" that runs as administrator and run this MSI file - as well as passes it the path to the log file.

I am searching for a way to pack this MSI and EXE into one EXE to distribute. I prefer doing it as part of my Visual studio project. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to embed it into the custom action and then extract it and save it to disk at runtime.

For more information, see the article *[Insert any binary file in C# assembly and extract it at runtime](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Insert-any-binary-file-in-C-assembly-and-extract-it-at-runtime.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for building self-extracting executables, and [Wikipedia lists several of the popular ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive). We ended up using [WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) in a post-build step in [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) for this task.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GenerateBootstrapper
          ApplicationFile="$(OutputName).msi"
          ApplicationName="$(ProductName)"
          BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
          OutputPath="$(OutputPath)"
          ComponentsLocation="Relative"
          CopyComponents="true"
          Culture="en"
          Path="$(ProductRoot)\Deployment"/>

    <ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="$(IconFile)">
        <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="IconFile"/>
    </ConvertToAbsolutePath>

    <ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="$(BannerFile)">
        <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="BannerFile"/>
    </ConvertToAbsolutePath>

    <!--  a      Adds files to archive -->
    <!--  -m     Sets compression level (0-store...3-default...5-maximal) -->
    <!--  -sfx   Sets self-extracting mode -->
    <!--  -ep1   Exclude base directory from included file paths -->
    <!--  -r     Add files recursively -->
    <!--  -iadm  Request administrator rights -->
    <!--  -z     Specify sfx configuration file -->
    <!--  -iicon<icon.ico>  Specify icon to use -->
    <!--  -iimg<banner.bmp>  Specify splash banner to use -->
    <Exec Command='$(ProductRoot)\..\buildTools\WinRAR\winrar.exe a -m3 -sfx -ep1 -r -iadm -iicon$(IconFile) -iimg$(BannerFile) -zsfx_config.txt $(OutputPath)\$(OutputSetupName) $(TargetPath) $(OutputPath)\setup.exe "$(BootstrapperDependency)"'/>
</Target>
```

In WiX 3.6, [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) should be able to handle that task, but I haven't experimented with it yet.